# Wrapper Class Error

Tags: visualforce, custom-object, wrapper-class

I have a custom object as Compitetor (fields as price,partnos,volume etc) ,created a vf page using controller and wrapper class .
but i get an Error as :Error:displayCompitetor Compile Error: Invalid identifier: Price_Offered__c at line 33 column 24

vf code:

```
<apex:page controller="displayCompitetor" >
 <apex:form >
  <apex:pageBlock title="General information">
   <apex:pageBlockSection columns="5" >
    <apex:dataTable value="{!comWrapper}" var="item"> 
     <apex:column width="200px">
                     <table width="250" border="0">                       
                     <tr> 
                     <td><b>Name :</b></td>
                     <td>{!item.CompitetorName }</td> 
                     </tr>                        
                     <tr> 
                     <td><b>Product Series :</b></td>
                     <td>{!item.Product_Series__cc}</td>
                     </tr>                         
                     <tr> 
                     <td><b>Price :</b></td>
                     <td>{!item.Price_Offered__cc} </td>
                     </tr>                        
                     <tr>
                     <td><b>Volume :</b></td>
                     <td>{!item.Volume__cc} </td>
                     <tr>
                     <td><b>DatePriceisvalid :</b></td>
                     <td>{!item.Date_Price_is_valid__cc} </td>
                     </tr>                     
                     </table>               
                     </apex:column>

    </apex:dataTable>

   </apex:pageBlockSection>
  </apex:pageBlock>
 </apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

Apex Class :

```
public class displayCompitetor {


  //Get the respective CustomQuote id
  ID CustomQuoteId;

  //Store the wrapped Compitetors
  public List<Compitetor__cWrapper> comWrapper{get;set;}

 //COnstructor 
 public displayCompitetor()
  {   
     CustomQuoteId= ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');  

 //Initialize list
 comWrapper = new List<Compitetor__cWrapper>();
 for(Compitetor__c tempCom :[select Name,Product_Series__c,Price_Offered__c,Volume__c, Date_Price_is_valid__c from Compitetor__c where CustomQuoteId=:CustomQuoteId])
 { 
    //create the object for the wrapper class
    Compitetor__cWrapper tempWrapper = new Compitetor__ctWrapper(tempCom);
    conwrapper.add(tempWrapper);
 }



  } //End of Constructor

  //Wrapper class for Compitetor
  public class CompitetorWrapper
  {      
     public String CompitetorName{get;set;}
     public String Product_Series__c{get;set;}
     public string Price_Offered__c{get;set;}
     public string Volume__c{get;set;}
     public string Date_Price_is_valid__c{get;set;}

     public Compitetor__cWrapper(Compitetor__c com)
       {
         CompitetorName=com.Name;
         Product_Series__cc=com.Product_Series__c;
         Price_Offered__cc=com.Price_Offered__c;
         Volume__cc=com.Volume__c;
         Date_Price_is_valid__cc =com.Date_Price_is_valid__c
       }//End of Wrapper constructor

 }//End of wrapper class 




//public String getComWrapper() {
 //   return null;
}
```

}

Comment: n.b. nikkey -- it is spelled `Competitor`, not compitetor; please learn how to properly format your post when inserting code to ensure all lines are included - use the button with the 1's and 0's to do that (I did it for you).  Also - it isn't really fair to SFSE users to make them figure out what is line 33 - annotate the line in question with a easily-seen comment

Comment: @crop1645:it was typo mistake while creating the custom object in my dev org.So i continued using the same .

Comment: Price_Offered__cc ?? It should be Price_Offered__c right?

Comment: @AmitBangad:i do get error at : public string Price_Offered__c{get;set;}

Comment: You should really make sure your code compiles before asking someone to look at it.

Answer (score 1):

Your VF page uses:

```
<td>{!item.Price_Offered__cc} </td>
```

The variable you declare is:

```
Price_Offered__c
```

You also have other spots where you name a variable one thing and then use a different name somewhere else.